# Sorting files and printing out them in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python, file, sorting

I need to write a python script that writes out a list of 10 names, reads the file back and prints out in alphabetical order

I kinda get what I have to do but how I do it is my problem, I don't know if you have to convert the text file into a list then use the sort() function or if I can do it just by splitting the lines.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
my_file = open("Names.txt", "w")

for i in range(1, 11):
    my_file.write(str(input("Please enter a name")) + ", \n")

my_file.close()

my_file = open("Names.txt", "r")
for line in my_file:
    print(line)

for line in my_file:
    my_file.sort()

my-file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are writing to the file fine

How about just

```
print "".join(sorted(open("Names.txt", "r")))
```

this works because when you iterate over a file thats open for reading it consumes lines of the file

incidentally that is also the reason your code doesnt work

when you do for `line in my_file` you consume the file and it leaves you at the end of the file

then when you do it a second time you are already at the end of the file so you never go inside the second loop

in addition to that it looks like you are trying to sort each name , (ie Susan -> Sansu)

Comment: This won't print each line individually, but it's probably a good enough answer for a homework question.

Comment: there fixed :P ... im guessing the -1 isnt you ... but it would be nice if whoever downvoted left a comment

Comment: Thanks for giving me the benefit of the doubt, no it wasn't me. I hate those drive-by downvotes too.

Comment: That's fantastic but is there a way to remove the \n from the outputs or even printing them off on a separate line?

Comment: ahh for some reason I was thinking the ending new line was stripped out automagically by this iteration thing ... my bad

Comment: +1.  For pedagogical purposes, I would write this with more lines.  Something like `with open ("Names.txt", "r") as f:lines = f.readlines();lines.sort();print ''.join(lines)` and then show the one-liner as well.

Comment: yeah but thats so much more pedestrian :P ... this is way more fun .... waaaay more fun ... tbh with homework questions i usually make them almost unintelligible to python novices... but its clear this guy at least made an honest effort of some sort

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
my_file = open("Names.txt", "w")

for i in range(1, 11):
my_file.write(str(input("Please enter a name")) + ", \n")

my_file.close()    
my_file = open("Names.txt", "r")
for line in sorted(my_file):
    print line

my-file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("Names.txt", "a+") as f: #  use with to open files as it closes them automatically
    for i in range(1, 11):
        f.write("{} \n".format(str(input("Please enter a name"))))
    f.seek(0) # go back to start  of file
    for line in f: # print each name
        print(line)
    f.seek(0) # go back to start again
    lines = sorted(f.readlines()) # sort the names
    with open("Names.txt", "w") as f1:  # write names in sorted order
        for line in lines: 
            f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Why open the file a second time?  Why not another `f.seek(0)`?  Also, the comment character is `#`, not `'` (see your first line).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski,because I prefer to reopen using "w" when rewriting to the same file and I think the `'` is obviously a typo considering the use of `#` for the other 5 comments